# ColdFusion Query -- Get index of column by column name

Tags: coldfusion

I have a column name and, for the sake of SpreadsheetSetCellFormula, I want to get the index of that column from its name.  This is important for expandability, as columns may be added or taken away in the future.

When I use queryName.ColumnList, ColdFusion automatically alphabetizes the list.  However, passing it into SpreadsheetAddRows dumps the columns in original order.  How can I get the index of a column from its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!--- get the column list, in the original order, as a coldfusion compatible array --->
<cfset variables.columnArray = createObject("java","java.util.Vector").init(
   createObject("java","java.util.Arrays").asList(
      query.getColumnList()
   )
)/>
<!--- get the index of the column. note that this is case sensitive. --->
<cfset variables.myColumnIndex = variables.columnArray.indexOf("MY_COLUMN")/>
```

No looping required.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should consider using Java more.  The lack of OO-style functions (like .indexOf) has been a major frustration.

Comment: It looks like this method also requires a " + 1", since Java uses 0-based arrays and CF uses 1-based.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: That sounds about right, unless you want something like myquery.getRow(rowIndex).getColumn(columnIndex) -- then you want your columnIndex to be 0 based. :)

Comment: @Josh - Keep in mind not all of the java stuff is "documented". So it is not as compatible with other CF engines (if that is a concern).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, however this may be VERY useful in your situation (I have used it in a similar situation)

This is taken from:
http://existdissolve.com/2010/11/quick-coldfusion-goodness/

```
columns = arrayToList(myquery.getMeta().getcolumnlabels())
```

gives you a list of the columns in their original order, with their original case sensitivity (not all upper case)

Comment: Looks like this would work with [listFindNoCase()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d80.html) or [listFind()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d84.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getMetaData()` function, which you can read about [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7dd9.html).  This function will return an array of Columns in the correct order, including some other information.  You would use it as follows:

```
getMetaData(queryName)
```

Comment: Is there any nice way to get the index I'm looking for without making a whole loop?